# Failed automated Android-UI-Tests due to java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, ant, robotium, android-library, ui-testing

In order to test my Android-App I'm using the UI-Testing tool [Robotium](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/). I've already experienced many problems with the build of projects and running tests at all because of the transitive lib-project dependencies and inability of android build tools to deal with them.

Please get introduced in my case reading my earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9977175/failed-automated-android-ui-tests-on-jenkins-server-due-to-complex-lib-project-d) to a problem and the corresponding [discussion](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21720) on solution.

Now, after certain time, i have included another library project, the [ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/), which my library project **B** is depending on. So i was forced again to apply my previous solution provided in the link above, in order to prevent that bug with lib-projects, and i've added following code to ant.properties of the test project:

```
android.library.reference.1=../lib-project
android.library.reference.2=../Android-ViewPagerIndicator/library

library.paths=com/mydomain/project/* com/actionbarsherlock/**
```

As i expected, the build worked. But the testcases to activities, which actually depended on the new library, haven't passed, and i encountered java.IllegalAccessError:

```
test:
     [echo] Running tests...
     [exec] 
     [exec] com.mydomain.project.projectb.test.unittests.EncodeTest:.
     [exec] com.mydomain.project.projectb.test.testcases.ServerCommTest:........
     [exec] com.mydomain.project.projectb.test.testcases.LoginTest:
     [exec] INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: shortMsg=java.lang.IllegalAccessError
     [exec] INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: longMsg=java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation
     [exec] INSTRUMENTATION_CODE: 0
```

I realized then, that ViewPagerIndicator was depending on Android-Support-v4 package, so i put its jar in test-projects libs directory, and tried again. I've encountered this time java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError for the activity classes:

```
test:
     [echo] Running tests...
     [exec] 
     [exec] com.mydomain.project.projectb.test.unittests.EncodeTest:.
     [exec] junit.framework.TestSuite$1:
     [exec] Failure in warning:
     [exec] junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Exception in constructor: testCreateAlbum (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.mydomain.project.activity.LoginActivity
     [exec]     at com.mydomain.project.test.testcases.ServerCommTest.<init>(ServerCommTest.java:29)
     ...
```

What could be the problem here? If i don't apply the fix in ant.properties file at all, i get the same error like in my another question...

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Problem is with your junit task's classpath. Not provided in your question...