# Ant build failing with "UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION (already added)"

Tags: android, ant

I've seen a lot of threads about this error, but none that cover my strange scenario. First the basics:

I've got 6 projects, all of which are scaled down test projects that mimic my application's structure and which I'm using just to try to get the build working. Their dependencies are as follows:

- *exampleLib* is a library that requires no other jars

  - contains Widget.java
- *exampleLib2* is a library that requires no other jars

  - contains Widget2.java
- *exampleLibNester* is a library that requires *exampleLib* and *exampleLib2*

  - contains WidgetPartDeux.java
- *exampleLibNester2* is a library that requires *exampleLib*, *exampleLib2*, and *exampleLibNester*

  - contains WidgetPartDeux2.java
- *exampleUser* is an application that requires *exampleLib*, *exampleLib2*, *exampleLibNester*, and *exampleLibNester2*

  - contains TheActivity.java
- *exampleTest* is a test application that instruments *exampleUser* and requires *exampleLib*, *exampleLib2*, and *exampleLibNester*

  - contains WidgetTest.java

When I build these applications using ant locally on windows they run fine and I can use `install test` to run the tests. When I try to build them on my CI server, which is running linux, I get the dreaded "already added" error message.

```
-dex:
  [dex] Converting compiled files and external libraries into /apps/pos360/jenkins/.hudson/jobs/James-Test/exampleLibUser/bin/classes.dex...
   [dx]
   [dx] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
   [dx] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/example/nester/WidgetPartDeux;
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:123)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:163)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:486)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:455)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$400(Main.java:67)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:394)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:245)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:131)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:109)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:418)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:329)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:206)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:174)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:91)
   [dx]
   [dx] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
   [dx] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/example/lib/Widget;
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:123)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:163)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:486)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:455)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$400(Main.java:67)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:394)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:245)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:131)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:109)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:418)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:329)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:206)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:174)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:91)
   [dx] 2 errors; aborting
```

I can look in the classes.jar files and see that exampleLibNester2 is pulling those classes into its jars, but I don't know how to prevent it from doing that nor why it does it on the linux box but not the windows one. Both SDKs have been updated to the latest version.

Comment: Have you read [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9513517/unexpected-top-level-exception-after-sdk-update) yet? Does it help?

Comment: Thhanks @yorkw. I've read that one and several others like it. My problem isn't merely libraries. I can get those working just fine. My problem is when there are nested libraries in prerequisite projects. I finally just merged all of the child libraries into a single project, but I'll leave the question open until the bounty expires in case someone knows of a better way.

Comment: I find it interesting that it works on your Windows machine and doesn't work on your Linux box. Do you mind checking if there are any stray jar files on any of the `lib` subfolders of the project? Or maybe you already make sure everything is using the newer `libs` mechanism? Maybe also check the version of proguard.jar on each environment.

Comment: When you write "is a library" do you mean "is an Android library project", "is a JAR", or something else? For these various dependencies, for those where the dependencies are Android library projects, are they all depending on the same Android library projects' folders, or are there multiple independent copies of the Android library projects?

Comment: @JosephJudistita: we're already using the new libs mechanism, and we're not using proguard. We will be, but we aren't released yet so all of our builds are debug ones.

Comment: @CommonsWare: yes, it's an android library project. There's only one copy of the library project, and it's referenced in project.properties.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Well, I tried reconstructing your project structure on my machine (Linux) and wasn't getting the error. Either I missed something or there is a local problem on your machine. You did check for any unexpected JAR files in your directories, right? Maybe try to pull a new copy of your projects from source control to a new folder and see if the problem persisted :)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it the project structure for Android builds changed as of R14.

I would suggest looking at your project build path and removing any folders ending in _src, per this article: 
[@foxykeep : How to fix the "conversion to Dalvik format failed"](http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/fix-the-conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-with-adt-14).  Despite the error name the stack trace is the same error and it looks like the same problem.

Comment: It's not. We crossed the SDK 14 hump quite a while ago. It's the reason we no longer update our SDKs immediately. We wait until tons of other people have had a chance to stumble onto Google's land mines.

Answer (score 0):

When you build your .jar file in library project. Don't add any permission on file AndroidManifest.xml (Pure AndroidManifest is enough). Just add all permissions you need into your main project Manifest file.

Or you can just simply import your library project to your main project and don't use .jar.